# Reuse a cached Spark RDD

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd

Is there a possibility in Spark to re-use a cached RDD in another application (or in another run of the same application)?

```
JavaRDD<ExampleClass> toCache = ... // transformations on the RDD
toCache.cache();                    // can this be reused somehow in another application or further runs?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Spark RDD cannot be used in other application or in another run.

You can connect Spark with for example [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/resources/introduction-hazelcast-imdg-apache-spark/) or [Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd) to save RDDs in memory. Other application will have possibility to read data saved in first application